# soup.find_all doesnt return anydata

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get the location of the houses but i dont get any data just "[]". In new to Python and newer to web scraping. Heres my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.inmuebles24.com/casas-en-venta-en-tijuana.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

location = soup.find_all(class_='posting-location go-to-posting')
print(location)
```

Comment: If the data you're trying to scrape is populated after page load via Javascript, you'd need to execute the Javascript so that the data is fetched. I believe Selenium is capable of that.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon a close examination, your code should work as expected. Other alternatives for extracting multiple css classes using `find_all` are included below

```py
location = soup.find_all('span',class_=['posting-location', 'go-to-posting'])

# or

location = soup.find_all(class_='posting-location go-to-posting')

# or

location = soup2.find_all('span',{'class':'posting-location go-to-posting'})
```

The above was tested after manually copying the source code/html of the page. I received 20 items

### Problem

Your real issue, lies in the website you are trying to scrape. The website has utilized measures to reduce bots and persons who may try to scrape their content by using a captcha block.

You may see this if you view the response of your request as follows

```py
print(page.text)
```

I have copied a snippet of this for your perusal:

```
![CDATA[\n    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },\n      b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};\n      b(function(){\n        var cookiesEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false;\n        if(!cookiesEnabled){\n          var q = document.getElementById(\'no-cookie-warning\');q.style.display = \'block\';\n        }\n      });\n  //]]>\n  </script>\n  <div id="trk_captcha_js" style="background-image:url(\'/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/nojs/h/transparent.gif?ray=5d997e89698b1414\')"></div>\n</form>\n\n              </div>\n            </div>\n\n            <div class="cf-column">\n              <div class="cf-screenshot-container">\n              \n                <span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>\n              \n              </div>\n            </div>\n          </div><!-- /.columns -->\n        </div>\n      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->\n\n      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">\n        <div class="cf-columns two">\n          <div class="cf-column">\n            <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>\n            \n            <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>\n          </div>\n\n          <div class="cf-column">\n            <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>\n            \n\n            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>\n\n            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>\n            \n              \n            \n          </div>\n        </div>\n      </div><!-- /.section -->\n      \n\n      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">\n  <p c
```

### Recommendations

You may consider finding an API or using a method allowed and approved by the site owners.

Comment: It does work, I tested it and got 20 items. It seems when you make a request to the page you are presented with a captcha block. I tested the above by copying the source from a regular browser. The problem isn't `soup.find_all` , it is that the web page isn't allowing you to scrape the page as is. you can confirm this by using `print(page.text)`. You'll see the captcha challenge message on screen. I'll update the answer with this message and tips to debug. If this helps, please mark the answer as accepted so that other stackoverflow users with similar issues may also find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that theres a captcha challenge with print(page.text). I will look for an API or to work on another project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
span_tags = soup.find_all('span')
for span in span_tags:
  if span['class'] == 'posting-location go-to-posting':
    print(span.text)
```

Comment: it game me Key Error : 'class'